# Linear Transformations between Spaces with Same Dimensions

Tags: linear-transformations

I need help. I was asked to write an essay about Linear Transformations between spaces with same dimensions. Which are the essentials topics to cover? What's the main difference between them and transformations that connect spaces with different dimensions?

Comment: For example : diagonalization, triangularization, powers of an endomorphism, equivalence : $f$ is one-to-one $\Leftrightarrow$ $f$ is onto $\Leftrightarrow$ $f$ is a automorphism of $E$...

Comment: They can be invertible.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent linear transformations by $m \times n$ matrices over some field $F$.

Same dimensions means we are talking about square matrices here.

One property is that you can multiply them nicely from both sides with another square matrix and the result is another square matrix.

And you can add them and stay within the square matrices.

More technically: square matrices form the vector space $M_n(F)$ over some field $F$, which has dimension $n^2$.

Some notable subsets are

- the general linear group $GL(n, F)$, which contains all invertible matrices, they represent the bijective linear transformations
- the special linear group $SL(n, F)$ of all matrices with determinant 1, which represent transformations that preserve volume and orientation
- the orthogonal group $O(n, F)$ of all matrices with $A^{-1} = A^T$ which represent operations that preserve lengths

Another interesting case is

- the symmetric group $S(n)$, consisting of all permutations of $n$ elements, which can be represented as square matrices with exactly one $1$ element per column and row, and otherwise $0$ elements

&c., &c.

A search on "square matrix" in your favourite search engine will yield many hits, I guess they show up through most of the stuff typically covered in a linear algebra lecture.